# Separating certain keys from an Array into two clearly distinct groups. How?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, key

I would like to add stuff out of an array and translate them. However, some items in the array I do not want to translate and so encapsulate them into special tags. In this example i've uset `<` `>`  but if you have suggestions/better iead's I'm open to them. I also thought of `{` `}` or `[` `]` and `*` `*` whichever you think is easiest.

```
<?php
# define the contents of my all time clients
$clients = array('<UNESCO>', 'Vrije Universiteit medical center');

# randomization engine
$keys = array_rand($clients, 3);    // get 3 random keys from your array
foreach ($keys as $key) {           // cycle through the keys to get the values

   # if this item is inbetween < > tags..
   if #??#######??########??#########??########??##

      # then put this item directly into randomList without translation
      $randomList .= "• " . $clients[$key]) . "<br/>";  // WORKS

   # all other items without <tags> are first translated via __() then added
   else $randomList .= "• " . __($clients[$key]) . "<br/>";  // WORKS
}?>
```

**Question: What should be on line 10 to make the IF statement complete?**
In other words, what is the logic in programming code that can match an item in the array being one of those special words that should not be translated and treaded differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to ditch the brackets before outputting the name. You could use this then:

```
// note that you need to test against $clients[ $key ], not $key
if( preg_match( '~^<(.*)>$~', $clients[ $key ], $matches ) )
{
    $randomList .= "• " . $matches[ 1 ] . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Awesome your question Saved my Sunday So to Speak! thanks very much!

Comment: Can I just replace `^<(.*)>$` to `^@(.*)@$` or even `^#(.*)#$` sothat way my exception items would be bit more visually appearing e.g.  **#WORD#**

Comment: @Sam: Yeah, those aren't reserved characters. If you find yourself using reserved characters, you should escape them with a backslash. See the reserved characters here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: interesting link, BUT, i see the `<` `>` as reserved characters, right? but they are not escaped in your (working) answer.... enlighten me please

Comment: Some, if not most reserved chars depend on context. `<>` are used to name patterns. For instance `(?<name>.*)` would be a (sub) pattern caught as $matches[ 'name' ]. Regular expression matching is clever enough to know this (since the patterns itself obide by the rules regular languages I believe). For more info on the matter, see the docs, as it could get very longwinded to explain all the intricacies of regexes here. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php

Answer (score 3):

Few possible solutions:

```
if (preg_match('~^<.*>$~', $clients[$key]))

if (strlen($clients[$key]) > 0 && $clients[$key][0] == '<' && substr($clients[$key], -1) == '>')
```

Comment: The intent is clear, but you should test against `$clients[ $key ]`, not `$key` itself.

Comment: @fireeyedboy: yep, thanks. Anyway, i've given a hint, not a complete solution to OP.

Comment: thanks for your broad possibilities the second one seems very accurate. With your starting proposal FireEyedBoy could finish the second half. A pity I cannot mark two questions as answer! Why not? I think its very old fashion to say that only ONE person is completely right... because in reality people based their ideas on others etc... So, I'm happy you have one more upvote than @FireEyedBoy that sort of compensates stuff :)

Comment: @Sam: I don't mind if you give zerkms the best answer vote. In all fairness: I continued on his answer indeed. I just didn't want to put all that in a comment. Code in comments suck, etc.